# Java GDB input not from terminal

Tags: java, input, stream, gdb

Im trying to quit the debugging session and it asks for user a input for verification.
I tried running this code fragment in my code

```
    stdin.println("quit");
    stdin.flush();
    stdin.println("y");  // this does not work..
    stdin.flush();
```

but it doesnt work..

How can i send input to gdb using this java external program??

```
public class Debugger extends Thread{

        public void run(){
        Process p = null;
        try {
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("gdb a.out --interpreter=console");
       new Thread(new SyncPipe(p.getErrorStream(), System.err)).start();
       new Thread(new SyncPipe(p.getInputStream(), System.out)).start();
        PrintWriter stdin = new PrintWriter(p.getOutputStream());

        stdin.flush();
        stdin.println("break main");
        stdin.flush();
        stdin.println("run");
        stdin.flush();
        stdin.println("s");
        stdin.flush();
        stdin.println("quit");
        stdin.flush();
        stdin.println("y");  // this does not work..
        stdin.flush();
       // stdin.close();


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
    }

class SyncPipe implements Runnable
{

    public SyncPipe(InputStream istrm, OutputStream ostrm) {
      istrm_ = istrm;
      ostrm_ = ostrm;

  }

  public void run() {

      try
      {   
           int length;
           byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

          for ( length = 0; (length = istrm_.read(buffer)) != -1; ){

              ostrm_.write(buffer, 0, length);
          } 

      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }


  }


  private final OutputStream ostrm_;
  private final InputStream istrm_;
}
```

GDB output:

```
GNU gdb (Ubuntu/Linaro 7.3-0ubuntu2) 7.3-2011.08
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "i686-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://bugs.launchpad.net/gdb-linaro/>...
Reading symbols from /home/charmae/workspace/AVT/a.out...done.
(gdb) Breakpoint 1 at 0x804853d: file fileg.c, line 7.
(gdb) Starting program: /home/charmae/workspace/AVT/a.out 

Breakpoint 1, main () at fileg.c:7
7       printf("input of x: ");
(gdb) 8     scanf("%d",&x);
(gdb) A debugging session is active.

    Inferior 1 [process 6341] will be killed.

Quit anyway? (y or n) [answered Y; input not from terminal]
```

Answer (score 0):

Run gdb setting `set confirm off`

For example:

```
gdb -ex run -ex "set confirm off" --args ./program [arg1] [arg2] [arg3]
```